# Is there a way to get the path of a directory?

Tags: r, directory

With the following

```
dir.create(paste0('hello ', Sys.Date()))
```

I created a directory whose name is `hello 2020-08-10` (today's date). How can I write a csv file inside it? I might use `setwd` command but it requires the path of the directory. Is there a way to get the path of a directory?

Comment: Are you looking for `getwd()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That directory is created as a subdirectory of your current working directory. Thus, you should be able to write your csv file with the relative path `"hello 2020-08-10/file.csv"`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have data to write from a data frame then you can achieve it this way. You can always get the path of the working directory using `getwd()`.

```
dir <- paste0('hello ', Sys.Date())
yourdf <- read.csv("file.csv")
wrtfile <- paste0(dir,"/filename.csv")
dir.create(dir)
write.csv(yourdf, file = wrtfile, row.names = FALSE)
```